# DevExpress Reporting : How to achieve below requirement in angular 5, End user reporting?

Tags: devexpress, devextreme, devexpress-mvc, devexpress-wpf, devextreme-angular

I have below requirement but not sure how to proceed.

I have a page where I have two sections

**Left section**:  Having list of report templates which user has saved previously by creating the .repx files, on select of this(left) section, right section will update.

**Right Section**: DevExpress designer to view/edit the repx.

Also I don't want to get individual .repx file from backed on click of each section, instead is it possible that I get all the section list with .repx file at a time and when user select the section then designer will load the selected repx file. ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]